# How to show data on frontend using Controller in Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to show data on front end using controller in Angular js but unable to do so I am able to take data from database that is mysql but don't know how to show it on frontend

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;
        console.log(password);
        if (email && password) {
            connection.query('select * from user where email = ? and password = ?', [email, password], function(err, result) {
                console.log(result);
                if (err) res.send(err);
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show your code/effort to accomplish this task.

Comment: module.exports = function(app){


    app.post('/login', function(req, res){
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;
        
        console.log(password);
    
        if(email && password){
            connection.query('select * from user where email = ? and password = ?', [email, password], function(err, result){
                console.log(result);
               if(err)
               res.send(err);

               res.redirect('/dashboard');
            });
        }  
    });
}

Comment: I am trying to give the code in the question but it give an error so i write the code in the comment please go throw it this code give an error that is                                                Error: Route.post require a callback function but return a object undefined